# Storage size of isn't known

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

This is part of an IOCTL switch case. I am getting the following error?

error: storage size of 'data' isn't known
error: 'mesg' undeclared (first use in this function)

```
case PASS_STRUCT:

        struct mesg{
            int pIDs[SIZE];
            int niceVal;
        };

        struct mesg data;

        ret = copy_from_user(&data, arg, sizeof(data));
        if(ret < 0){
            printk("PASS_STRUCT\n");
            return -1;  
        }

        printk("Message PASS_STRUCT : %d\n",data.niceVal);
        break;
```

SIZE value is set before creating mesg.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> struct mesg{
>     int pIDs[SIZE];
>     int niceVal;
> };
> ```
>
> SIZE value is set before creating mesg.

In C `SIZE` needs to be a true compile-time constant to use it like that. Something like:

```
#define SIZE 10
```

You also should move the structure declaration outside the `switch`.

Comment: the SIZE of the pIDs array changes upon each all to this driver, it is not defined as #define SIZE 10. What can be done?

Comment: @kani Yeah. It will bring other changes though.

Comment: Hmm yeah :-( can you have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130689/passing-struct-to-device-driver-through-ioctl. I define SIZE before calling PASS_STRUCT can't any thing done in that code?

Comment: @kani Read more about `C` and Linux internals: it will be easier than just dragging the code one question to the other

Comment: Will #define SIZE 10 be able to be changed at runtime?

Comment: @kani No, once you define it it becomes "text".

Comment: with a the same code above, now am getting this error: expected expression before 'struct'. What do you think of this?

Comment: @kani, If you want the array size to be dynamic, then you really want an `int numIDs` element and change `pIDs` to a pointer (`int * pIDs`).  Then the driver will have to allocate a memory space the size of `numIDs*sizeof(int)`, then do a `copy_from_user()` to that memory space using `pIDs`.