# Is int arr[ ] valid C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, incomplete-type

I am trying to understand if writing `int arr[];` is valid in C++. So take for example:

```
int a[]; //is this valid?
extern int b[];//is this valid?

int (*ptrB)[]; //is this valid?
struct Name
{
    int k[]; //is this valid?
};
void func()
{
    ptrB++; //is this valid?
}
int a[10];
int b[10];
void bar()
{
    ptrB = &b;//is this valid?
    ptrB++; //is this valid?
}
int main()
{
    int c[];//is this valid?
    extern int d[]; //is this valid?
}

int c[10];
int d[10];
```

I have read some comments on SO stating that `int p[];` is not valid C++. So I wanted to know in what situations is this valid/invalid. For that I wrote the above snippet and want to understand through this example.

Comment: [Arrays of unknown bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Arrays_of_unknown_bound).

Comment: "I have read some comments on SO stating that int p[]; is not valid C++.": It is likely that these were specifically in reference to `int p[]` as a data member of a class. This is allowed in C as last member of a `struct` and called a _flexible array member_ there, but is not allowed in C++. Some compilers allow it in C++ mode as an extension anyway (if strict conformance flags aren't used).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us look at each of the cases.

##### Case 1

Here we have the statement

```
int a[]; //this is a definition so size must be known
```

This is **not valid**.

##### Case 2

Here we have the statement:

```
extern int b[];//this is a declaration that is not a definition
```

This is **valid**. Here the type of `b` is **incomplete**. Also, `b` has **external linkage**.

##### Case 3

Here we have:

```
int (*ptrB)[];
```

This is **valid**. We say that `ptrB` is a *pointer to an incomplete type*.

##### Case 4

Here we have:

```
struct Name
{
    int k[]; //NOT VALID
};
```

This is **not valid** as from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type):

> Any of the following contexts requires type T to be complete:

> - declaration of a **non-static class data member** of type T;

##### Case 5

Here we have:

```
void func()
{
    ptrB++; //NOT VALID
}
```

This is **not valid** as from [postfix increment's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec):

> The operand expr of a built-in postfix increment or decrement operator must be a modifiable (non-const) lvalue of non-boolean (since C++17) arithmetic type or **pointer to completely-defined** object type.

##### Case 6

Here we have:

```
void bar()
{
    ptrB = &b;//NOT VALID
}
```

This is **not valid** as from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type):

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown bound and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and complete later on; the array types at those two points ("array of unknown bound of T" and "array of N T") are **different types**.

##### Case 7

Here we have:

```
void bar()
{
    ptrB++; //NOT VALID
```

This is **not valid** as from [cppreferene](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type):

> The **type** of a pointer to array of unknown bound, or to a type defined by a typedef declaration to be an array of unknown bound, **cannot be completed**.

So we will get the same error as in case 5.

##### Case 8

Here we have:

```
int main()
{
    int c[]; 
}
```

This is **not valid** since this is a definition and so size **must be** known.

##### Case 9

Here we have:

```
int main()
{
    extern int d[]; non-defining declaration
}
```

This is **valid**. `d` has **external linkage**.

Comment: Is case 4 valid C, however? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26183999/17635987

Comment: @kirjosieppo In the link you posted, it is written that *"As a special case, the last element of a structure with **more than one** named member may have an incomplete array type..."* . So i am not 100% sure if case 4 is valid in `C` since it has only one member and in the quote it is written that "for more than one". I think case 4 is invalid in C according to the above quoted statement.

Comment: Type of b actually complete but is equivalent to a pointer.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie No, it is incomplete. To verify this you can use `sizeof`. See [demo1](https://onlinegdb.com/WVN_ACh5m)  and [demo2](https://onlinegdb.com/lSPybaBj6).