# sizeof(char[]) in a struct member with no size specified

Tags: c++, sizeof, flexible-array-member

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct inotify_event {
  int wd;
  uint32_t mask;
  uint32_t cookie;
  uint32_t len;
  char name[];
};

struct inotify_event_no_name {
  int wd;
  uint32_t mask;
  uint32_t cookie;
  uint32_t len;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "sizeof(int): " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizeof(inotify_event): " << sizeof(inotify_event) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizeof(inotify_event_no_name): " << sizeof(inotify_event_no_name) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(int): 4
sizeof(inotify_event): 16
sizeof(inotify_event_no_name): 16
```

The `len` field counts all of the bytes in `name`, including the null bytes; the length of each `inotify_event` structure is thus `sizeof(struct inotify_event)+len`.

Why does `inotify_event` have the same size as `inotify_event_no_name`?

Comment: `char name[];` as member is a non standard extension. Also size of structs is not mandated by the standard. You should specify what compielr you are using (and what flags you used)

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) works. It's not part of the structure size, you have to explicitly allocate memory for it. For example by using `inotify_event* event reinterpret_cast<inotify_event*>(new char[sizeof(*event) + length_of_name + 1]);`

Comment: I tried to figure out why the location of the next inotify_event is calculated through `sizeof(struct inotify_event)+len` without considering the size of `char name[]`. Now the confusion has cleared. Thank you all!

Comment: Note: Compile with `-pedantic` on a GCC or GCC-like toolchain and get warnings about non-Standard code.

Comment: [Is `int arr[\]` valid C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631288/is-int-arr-valid-c)