# C pass variable size 2-D array to function

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to refactor my code to make it better/more readable so I'm trying change a 2-D variable array allocation as follows

```
// OLD CODE
int **map;
        map = calloc(number, sizeof(int *));
        if (!(map)) {
            free(map);
            return 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            map[i] = calloc(number, sizeof(int));
            if (!(map[i])) {
                while (--i >= 0) {
                    free(map[i]);
                }
                free(map);
                return 1;
            }
        }

// NEW CODE
int (*map)[number] = malloc(sizeof (int[number][number]));
if (!(map)){
    free(map);
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that all my functions that use map take `int **map` and by changing the declaration of map like i did the IDE tells me `incorrect type int[]* instead of int**`
What should i use instead of `int**`? Using `int[]* map` in the function declaration tells me `can't resolve variable map`

Comment: `type func(int n, int (*map)[n]);` call `func(number, map);`

Comment: Do yourself a favour and just create a flat array, then reference rows by array[y*width+x] = value;

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean i was thinking about that, is there a way to allocate half the size of the map and not have to worry about order of indexes? in my map position [i][j] and [j][i] will always have the same value but right now i allocate twice the needed size to not have to worry about the order of i and j.

Comment: To be clear, new code `map` is not a 2D array.  It is a "pointer to array number of int".  Old `map` is a [pointer to pointer to int](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+**map%3B)

Comment: array[ y*width-y + x]

Comment: Commenting going wrong. The formula is not right.

Comment: @JohnSmith Your current functions take a pointer, a pointer to an array of pointers.  `int (*map)[number] = malloc(...);` allocates an array of memory  of `int`.  There does not exist an equivalent array of pointers to pass to the functions with the new allocation code.  Aside from the multiple `malloc()` calls in the "old" code, what is wrong with it?

Comment: BTW: why the -1 in `calloc((number - 1), sizeof(int *))`? Certainly old code is incorrect with the following `for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            map[i] = calloc(number, sizeof(int));...`

Comment: @chux as i said, i would like to make the code easier to read, also it would be a plus to have all the cells allocated near each other in memory. as for the minus 1 it was a typo my bad

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the below code is not a C99 alternative [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635207/c-pass-variable-size-2-d-array-to-function?noredirect=1#comment72403744_42636123), but a GCC extension.

[Undocumented GCC Extension: VLA in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058760/undocumented-gcc-extension-vla-in-struct)

---

As a <strike>C99</strike> GCC extension alternative to `int (*map)[number] = malloc(sizeof (int[number][number]));` for code simplification and maintain compatibility with existing function set, allocate all the memory needed with 1 `*alloc()` call.

This does require that when code is done with the `map`, all the memory is free'd with one `free(map)`.  Further, individual rows of `map[]` can no longer be re-allocated, but can be swapped within the `map[]`.

```
int **map_allocate(size_t row, size_t column) {
  struct {
    int *ip[row];        // Array of pointers, followed by a ...
    int i[row][column];  // 2D array of int
  } *u;
  u = calloc(1, sizeof *u);
  if (u == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i<row; i++) {
    u->ip[i] = u->i[row];
  }
  return &u->ip[0];
}
```

Note: no casting and field `i[][]` is properly aligned.

Comment: Structs cannot contains VLAs

Comment: @M.M Interesting.  Yet `u` here is is not a `struct`, but a pointer to one - but I'd expect that to not make enough difference.  One compiler accepted it (waring well enabled - or so I thought - and hence this post) and another warned, as you say, "a member of a structure or union cannot have a variably modified type".  I shall review.

Comment: @M.M Well it looks like I'm back to the drawing board.  Too bad , it did look like a nifty solution.

Answer (score 0):

To use one allocation with standard code, [unlike the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636123/2410359), is a bit trickier as one needs to insure that a combined memory allocation of pointers and `int` needs to meet alignment concerns in the unusual case of `int` alignment requirements exceed pointer alignment ones.  This is more easily shown with `long long` as below.

If this makes "code easier to read" is left to OP's judgment.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long long **map_allocate_ll(size_t row, size_t column) {
  long long  **map;
  long long  *ints;

  size_t pointers_sz = sizeof *map * row;
  // extend pointer size to `*ints` boundary
  pointers_sz = (pointers_sz + sizeof *ints - 1)/sizeof *ints * sizeof *ints;
  size_t ints_sz = sizeof *ints * row * column;
  printf("psize %zu, isize %zu\n", pointers_sz, ints_sz);

  map = calloc(1, pointers_sz + ints_sz);
  if (map == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  ints = (void*) ((char*) map + pointers_sz);
  printf("map    %p\n", (void *) map);
  for (size_t i = 0; i<row; i++) {
    map[i] = &ints[i * column];
    printf("map[%zu] %p\n", i, (void *) map[i]);
  }
  return map;
}

int main() {
  free(map_allocate_ll(5,3));
}
```

Sample output

```
psize 24, isize 120
map    0x80081868
map[0] 0x80081880
map[1] 0x80081898
map[2] 0x800818b0
map[3] 0x800818c8
map[4] 0x800818e0
```