# memory management for a dynamically allocated 2D space

Tags: c, malloc

everyone:
I just come across an approach to allocate a 2D matrix in C. While practicing it, I'm confused about an unknown bug.

here is the function, first version:

```
//first version
static int ** my2DAlloc(int rows, int cols){
    int ** array;
    int * array_head;
    int i;
    int len = sizeof(int*)*rows + sizeof(int)*rows*cols + 1;
    array = (int**)malloc( len );
    memset(array, 0, len);

    array_head = (int *) (array + rows);
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = array_head + i*cols ;

    return array;
}
```

I don't have any problem with this version. However, I've tried to change the code a little, as the following:

```
//second version
static int ** my2DAlloc(int rows, int cols){
    int ** array;
    int * array_head;
    int i;
    int len = sizeof(int*)*rows + sizeof(int)*rows*cols + 1;
    array = (int**)malloc( len );
    memset(array, 0, len);

    //array_head = (int *) (array + rows);
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = (int *) (array + rows + i*cols);   // <--- the major difference

    return array;
}
```

Regarding this second version, it seems fine to write data to the matrix and read data out. 
But when I try to free the allocated space, I get system error like:

```
free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000020df010
```

It seems to be some memory error. But I could not figure out the problem. 
Could anyone help me out?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: How do you write the line of code where you free the space?

Comment: `array` is `int**`. `array_head` is `int*`. Both are different.

Comment: Do you really intend to return a pointer to a pointer of int?  As in, are you looking for an array of int pointers?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: If it's a 2D matrix of integers your looking for, then len should be sizeof(int) * rows * cols.

Comment: @jwdonahue What this seems to be is a 2D matrix of integers, but it has a header containing pointers to each row.

Comment: So it's like a matrix implemented as an array of pointers to rows, but it ensures that the rows are contiguous with each other and the pointer array.

Comment: The only value I can see in this design is that it's good for locality, and you can free the entire thing with one call to `free()`.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree, but I just wanted to make sure that this is the OP's intent.

Comment: `int len = sizeof(int*)*rows + sizeof(int)*rows*cols + 1;` is wrong size for various reasons: First drop the +1.  2nd type should be `size_t` 3rd: most important: code does not insure proper aliment of the `int`.  This _may_ work for OP, but is is not correct in general.

Comment: The code will fail on a platform where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`. This would write out of bounds for access to latter parts of the array, causing heap corruption (and perhaps therefore, failure of free)

Comment: @M.M Once again thanks for the good feed back

Comment: See [C pass variable size 2-D array to function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42652072/2410359)

Comment: I just use free(array) to free the allocated memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the second version is that you're doing the pointer arithmetic on an `int **` instead of `int *`, because you have the cast outside the arithmetic.

```
for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
    array[i] =  ((int *)(array + rows) + i*cols);   // <--- the major difference
```

Comment: Hi, Barmar, you are right, thanks for pointing out the issue.