# error: too many initializers for const

Tags: c++, c++11

Why do I get the following error

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 aaa.cpp
```

> aaa.cpp:15:2: error: too many initializers for ‘const aaaa::Fruit_List [0]’
>
> };
>
> ^

when compiling the following code:

```
class aaaa
{  // without wrapping in class the code compiles fine
    const int a=7; // compiles fine

    struct Fruit_List{
        int index;
        int length;
    } const fruit_list[]={ // error: if I put 5 in braket the code compiles fine
        {0,3},
        {1,2},
        {2,5},
        {3,1},
        {4,7}
    };
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I write the code without wrapping in the class, it would compile fine. Giving the length of the array will suppress compiler error. But insist of putting the code inside the class and avoid giving the array size as I may add any member later and I want to leave the array length determination to the compiler.

Strongly, please avoid linking to any inappropriate question.

**Update**

Thanks to juanchopanza's comment. Now I know that even this simpler code does not compile:

```
class aaaa
{
    const int a[]={7,4,5};
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't allow data members of type `T[]`. You need `T[N]` where `N` is a constant expression. Are you asking why it isn't allowed, or are you just after quotes from the standard that confirm it isn't?

Comment: @fredrik sorry of ambiguity. i fixed it.

Comment: Even if you remove `const`, it still gives an error.

Comment: @juanchopanza previously i used the code like `int a[]={1,2,3,4,5}` a lot. Do you mean this type of coding is now forbidden in C++? or mean that here is not the case I can enjoy leaving array length to the compiler?

Comment: No, I said "C++ doesn't allow **data members** of type T[]. I guess `a` is not a data member. In a class, you can have `T = {....}` or `T{.....}` where `T` is a complete type. `Q[]` doesn't satisfy that.

Comment: What juanchopanza is saying is that "it makes a difference that `fruit_list` is inside a class, vs. inside a function". If it is inside a class, it needs to have a constant size.

Comment: How about linking to a [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152171/too-many-initializers-for-int-0-c) and the relevant comments from [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) himself?

Comment: @MatsPetersson, Now my question is that, why compiler is unable to find the array length. It does not seem to be hard for compiler.

Comment: @dmg, :) At the time of posting question i searched a lot. But thought it is related to the array of structure!

Comment: It is not UNABLE to, it is NOT ALLOWED according to the standard. (The error message could be clearer, but the error is not that the compiler "can't count", but "you didn't write a size in the array")

Comment: How come it is allowed in a function but not in a class? Does it have any philosophy?

Comment: @barej My best guess is that because in a function you are doing allocation. In the class description you are not.

Comment: That question you'd have to ask the C++ standards committee... ;) My guess is that it makes it hard to determine the size of the whole struct in a meaningfull way. What if you do: `class a { const int b[]; }; ... const int a::b = { 1,2,3,4,5 };` which I believe is allowed if there is a fixed size... What if the `a::b = ..` is in another file?

Comment: Thanks to all guys helping. The problem seems to be simpler that what I thought. @juanchopanza has mentioned the exact point. you may post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably understand, by *wrapping it into a class*, your supposed constants are no longer *names that refer to an object with a fixed value given at initializing the constant*. Instead, you are now declaring constant data members, which are like non-constant data members, and exist in each instance in that class on their own. The value you provide is nothing more than a *default* value for initializing the constant member in the constructor.

Consider this example:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

struct Demo {
  const int args[3];
  Demo() : args{1,2,3} {}
  Demo(int x) : args{x,x,x} {}
  Demo(int y, int z) : args{y, z} {}
};

int main(void)
{
  Demo d1;
  Demo d2(1,2);
  std::cout << d2.args[0] << ' ' << d2.args[1] << ' '
            << d2.args[2] << '\n';  // outputs "1 2 0"
  return 0;
}
```

Not all of the constructors initialize `Demo::args` with the same amount of values. This is valid, and the remaining elements are zero-filled. The initialization you provide in a class for non-static data member is just syntactic sugar for using that value in every constructor where no explicit value for that member is specified in the init list, so the example above could also be written this way:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

struct Demo {
  const int args[3] = {1,2,3};
  Demo() {}
  Demo(int x) : args{x,x,x} {}
  Demo(int y, int z) : args{y, z} {}
};

int main(void)
{
  Demo d1;
  Demo d2(1,2);
  std::cout << d2.args[0] << ' ' << d2.args[1] << ' '
            << d2.args[2] << '\n';  // outputs "1 2 0"
  return 0;
}
```

The initializer at the member `Demo::args` is not *the* initializer, but just *one* initializer, while constructors may specify different ones. This is most likely why size deduction is not allowed, just like you can not use `auto` on non-static data members.

If you just meant to put the name of a single named entity with a constant value all the time while your program is running into the namespace provided by a class, but did not want to get the ability to specivy different values in some constructor, use a `static` constant inside the class.