# C++ Embedded System Morse Code

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I understand the error with my code. I'm trying to initialize an array within a class, which is not allowed because

> by wrapping it into a class, your supposed constants are no longer
>   names that refer to an object with a fixed value given at initializing
>   the constant. Instead, you are now declaring constant data members,
>   which are like non-constant data members, and exist in each instance
>   in that class on their own. The value you provide is nothing more than
>   a default value for initializing the constant member in the
>   constructor.
>   [error: too many initializers for const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123840/error-too-many-initializers-for-const)

Morse Code characters can be up to six characters long with units being the DOTS or DASHES. Accordingly, I have an array that I want hold up to six spots. The catch, is that I'm using an Arduino Uno, so memory is a concern. How can I write my code to be able to do this with the lowest memory usage, or simply a working example of what I'm trying to accomplish without resorting to the STL.
code.h

```
#include "Arduino.h"
const short DOT = 1000 / 2;
const short DASH = 3000 / 2;
class Code
{
public:
    Code();
    Code(short short1);
    Code(short short1, short short2);
    Code(short short1, short short2, short short3);
    Code(short short1, short short2, short short3, short short4);
    Code(short short1, short short2, short short3, short short4, short short5);
    Code(short short1, short short2, short short3, short short4, short short5, short short6);
    ~Code();
private:
    short letterMakeUp[];
};
```

code.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "code.h"
Code::Code()
{

}

Code::Code(short short1) : letterMakeUp{ short1 }
{

};
Code::Code(short short1, short short2) : letterMakeUp{short1, short2}
{

}
Code::Code(short short1, short short2, short short3) : letterMakeUp{short1, short2, short3}
{

}
Code::Code(short short1, short short2, short short3, short short4) : letterMakeUp{ short1, short2, short3, short4 }
{

}
Code::Code(short short1, short short2, short short3, short short4, short short5) : letterMakeUp{ short1, short2, short3, short4, short5 }
{

}
Code::Code(short short1, short short2, short short3, short short4, short short5, short short6) : letterMakeUp{ short1, short2, short3, short4, short5, short6 }
{

}
```

characters.h

```
Code Letters[26] =
 {
    { DOT, DASH },
    { DASH, DOT, DOT, DOT },
    { DASH, DOT, DASH, DOT },
    { DASH, DOT, DOT },
    { DOT },
    ...
};
```

Comment: I hope your platform can handle a little bit of overhead. Instead of `short letterMakeUp[];`, use `std::vector<short> letterMakeUp;`.

Comment: Otherwise you'll need six or seven classes.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<bool>` (e.g. `true` for dots, `false` for dashes) since it's guaranteed to be space-efficient.

Comment: You know, you *can* initialize an array within a class. Your 2nd sentence is most misleading.

Comment: @juanchopanza it seemed to match up with other articles I read. How so?

Comment: You have only 26 characters, is it really a problem to have a table like `short[26][7]`?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. If you want to do morse code translation using as little RAM as possible, this is not the way to do it

Comment: @Crysis You must have misunderstood the articles or data member initialization.

Comment: why don't just store the dots/dashes in a bit?

Comment: @MattMcNabb How would you suggest doing it? XY problem? Is an OOP method not the best way to go about this?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Honestly, because I'm new to this and didn't think about it. The reason I used the short is because Arduino measures the time in milliseconds, and I thought I'd just do it with shorts. Didn't think of bits.

Comment: @Crysis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It's obvious that I have the XY problem here. So, what is the best method to go about creating a Morse Code application? Should I abandon the OOP method?

Comment: I'll probably just end up using a switch case statement, but I'm still going to work on an OOP method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are part of the class size, means sizeof(Code) should be equal to:

`sizeof(letterMakeUp)` which equal to `sizeof(short) * countof(letterMakeUp)`

But a class must have fixed size.

means `sizeof(Code)` must be the same for each `Code` object.

If it is not the case, you won't be able to create arrays, vectors, etc.

Therefore the best solution is to use `vector`, you can also declare the array dynamically.

One more option is to use some `MAX_ARRAY` as constant for all arrays, and keep also the actual count of array.

Comment: What would be the best approach to creating a Morse Code program like this? I was told to use a bool array, but I still run into the same array problem if I continue with this approach to the program.