# `Too many initializers` for for array setup in RTEMS driver definition

Tags: c++, c, rtems

### Background

I am using RTEMS and trying to set up a native NFS client. Although i have included this correctly there are not enough dynamic driver entries available for the Driver. You can seek more information [here](https://docs.rtems.org/releases/rtemsdocs-4.9.2/share/rtems/html/ada_user/ada_user00416.html).

### Implementation

In order to set up the extra dynamic drivers one needs to add NULL elements to a large table of free drivers. See the following:

```
#define NULL_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY \
 { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}


#ifdef CONFIGURE_INIT
  rtems_driver_address_table Device_drivers[] = {
    #ifdef CONFIGURE_BSP_PREREQUISITE_DRIVERS
      CONFIGURE_BSP_PREREQUISITE_DRIVERS,
    #endif
    #ifdef CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_PREREQUISITE_DRIVERS
      CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_PREREQUISITE_DRIVERS,
    #endif

   ...

    #ifdef CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_EXTRA_DRIVERS
      CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_EXTRA_DRIVERS,
    #endif
    #ifdef CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_NULL_DRIVER
      NULL_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY
    #elif !defined(CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_CONSOLE_DRIVER) && \
        !defined(CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_CLOCK_DRIVER) && \
        !defined(CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_RTC_DRIVER) && \
        !defined(CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_STUB_DRIVER) && \
        !defined(CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_IDE_DRIVER) && \
        !defined(CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_ATA_DRIVER) && \
        !defined(CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_EXTRA_DRIVERS)
      NULL_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY
    #endif
  };
#endif
```

Essentially what this is doing is building the device driver table ...

A deice driver looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
  rtems_device_driver_entry initialization_entry; /* initialization procedure */
  rtems_device_driver_entry open_entry;        /* open request procedure */
  rtems_device_driver_entry close_entry;       /* close request procedure */
  rtems_device_driver_entry read_entry;        /* read request procedure */
  rtems_device_driver_entry write_entry;       /* write request procedure */
  rtems_device_driver_entry control_entry;     /* special functions procedure */
}   rtems_driver_address_table;
```

### Problem

The problem which may be exceptionally simple is that when i build this i get the following error:

```
confdefs.h:568: error: too many initializers for 'rtems_driver_address_table'
```

From looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152171/too-many-initializers-for-int-0-c) this appears to be a problem compiling with an unspecified number of table elements. What I don't understand is that this is currently **working** in that if I specify the `NULL_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY` with 7 `NULL`s (the number i need), it will fail, but with 6 `NULL`s it works perfectly fine?

As far as i can tell there is no definition as to the size of this table or its elements? Any ideas?

Comment: is `rtems_driver_address_table` some other variable? it looks like a typedef in this code snippet....

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yep, so i think you have cottoned on to my problem. I was just looking at the array incorrectly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a silly mistake...

The way this table works is that the NULL table entry:

```
#define NULL_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY \
 { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}
```

Is actually an entry in the array which corresponds to an `rtems_driver_address_table`. This driver has 6 elements and i was trying to have 7. The solution to this was to add an extra null entry as follows:

```
 rtems_driver_address_table Device_drivers[] = {

    ...

    #ifdef CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_NULL_DRIVER
      NULL_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY,
      NULL_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY // Add extra entry here!

   ...

  };
```