# How to initialize the LeastMaxValue template param in counting_semaphore?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++20, semaphore

I have a use case where I need to use `counting_semaphore` as a data member in a class. If it were a global variable, I could've omitted the template argument, and it would've been default initialized. [But as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026916/class-template-argument-deduction-in-member-variables), in case of a member variable, the template argument needs to be specified, and in our case it has to be a compile-time constant.

So, I'm not sure what to initalize the value of `LeastMaxValue` to? Are there any heuristics for it that you use, or is there a way I can still use the implementation defined default value for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would look at how the data member will be used and determine an upper bound on what the semaphore needs to count. This upper bound is an appropriate `LeastMaxValue`.

It is not always possible to find such a bound, though. If you have no way of bounding the maximum the data member needs to handle, you could use the largest possible value, `std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max()`.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to initializing it to the max possible value? And if there aren't, why don't we always initialize it to that as the default value?

Comment: @tarun26 The answer to that would be pretty similar to the answer to the following: *Are there any drawbacks to using `long long`? And if there aren't, why don't we always use `long long` (instead of other integer types)?*

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. But this means that there's a certain default value already for it, but why can't I access that with some macro, etc. and use it in case I have to use the type within a class? Also, does the value of max() depend on LeastMaxValue that we provide?