# why does int arr[]={0,3,2,4,5,6,7};give error and int arr[7]={0,3,2,4,5,6,7}; not

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class Test
{   
   private:
   int array[]={0,2,4,6,8,10,12};//this line is the root cause of the error but why ?   
   public :
   void compute();
};
void Test::compute()
{
    int result =0;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        result += array[i];
    }
        cout<<result;
}
int main()
{
    Test obj;
    obj.compute();
    return 0;
}
```

If I replace `int array[]` in the above code with `array[7]` then the program compiles and runs with warnings.

Comment: [I believe this has already been answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152171/too-many-initializers-for-int-0-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike an array in any other scope, an array in a class cannot be sized by it's initializer.  The initializer is just syntactic sugar telling the compiler what to use to initialize the member.  That means what you really have is

```
class Test
{   
   private:
   int array[]; 
   public :
   void compute();
   Test(): array({0,2,4,6,8,10,12}) {}
};
```

which can't work as there is no size information for the array.

It works when you specify a size, because now there is actually a valid size.  If you want to be able to have something like

```
int array[]={0,2,4,6,8,10,12};
```

in the class then use a `std::vector` instead like

```
std::vector<int> array={0,2,4,6,8,10,12};
```