# too many initializers for 'int [0]' while setting the parameters for HSV histogram calculation

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new in opencv and I want to calculate HSV histogram. I am refering the code provided in this link. https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html

I am using opencv version 3.3.1 and facing the following errors errors.

Using the same code, I did not do anychanges in the code except changing the image for HSV histogram. Where detectPerson is the video frame and hsv is cv mat object.

Anyone plzz help I am stuck here.

```
int h_bins = 50, s_bins = 60;
int histSize[] = {h_bins, s_bins};
// hue varies from 0 to 179, saturation from 0 to 255
float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };
// Use the 0-th and 1-st channels
int channels[] = { 0, 1 };
cv::Mat hist_hsv, hist_hsv2;

cvtColor(detectPerson, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV );            
calcHist( &hsv, 1, 0, Mat(), hist_hsv, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
normalize( hist_hsv, hist_hsv, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
```

Errors

```
int channels[] = { 0, 1 };
error: too many initializers for 'int [0]'
int histSize[] = {h_bins, s_bins}
error: too many initializers for 'int [0]'
float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
error: too many initializers for 'float [0]'
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
error: too many initializers for 'float [0]'
```

Comment: Looks like something might be broken with your compiler.  What happens if you just try to compile `int main() { int foo[] = {1, 2}; }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [too many initializers for 'int \[0\]' c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152171/too-many-initializers-for-int-0-c) It seems you haven't give us [mcve]. I guess you have not closed some your class definition when the line `int channels[] = { 0, 1 };` comes.

Comment: I am working on ROS, and using opencv in ROS

Comment: @NathanOliver I checked I closed all the classes and function body

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is defective, although this perplexes me since such code would be one of the first things in a compiler regression test suite.

`int channels[] = { 0, 1 };` is required by the C++ standard to be equivalent to `int channels[2] = { 0, 1 };`

It appears that your compiler assumes 0 as the default, to yield `int channels[0] = { 0, 1 };` for which, in standard C++, a diagnostic must be given since zero length arrays are not supported.

Does switching off any purported variable length array support fix it?

Comment: yes when I put int channels[2] = { 0, 1 }; it fixed..

Comment: so can I use int channels[2] = { 0, 1 }; it will be correct for HSV histogram calculation??

Comment: It ought to be, but that could be down to the specifics of the histogram you're using.

Comment: I am using the calcHist function which takes these parameters..